# Answers related to font switching software are downvoted and deleted

Tags: support, down-votes, deleted-answer

I wanted to ask why my answer to my own question was downvoted and deleted here: https://superuser.com/a/409577/89415, it is about switching a font. (I guess now only an admin can see it)

My other answer here https://superuser.com/a/449815/89415 was also downvoted at around the same time, leading me to think if any font switching software is prohibited to be mentioned here.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but it is not related to font switching software

Comment: Second post's editing history might give a clue: it's probably a user who assumes you're advertising one of the programs you mention. We have a problem with low reputation users posting links to software without a proper explanation why it works. The second post looks a bit like that, and the first one might have turned up in a search for the program name, despite having real content.

Comment: There is no general policy against font substitution software on this site by the way.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, and what's the proper channel to undelete my answer?

Comment: and would this be a case that someone abuse the downvote, and admin didn't bother to check before delete?

Comment: @lulalala Proper channel to get it undeleted is meta (so you did it right), or flag yourself to state your case. Users and moderators aren't perfect. I tried to explain how those flags could happen without malicious intent above.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, but would that admin now know to at least investigate a little bit next time? (or how can I tell him/her)

Comment: @lulalala First, there is no "admin", (well there is, but they mostly deal with Core engine dev). the site is community run. While we try to investigate as much as possible, there are chances of few things slipping here and there, we are human after all. That's where Meta comes in. raise a meta question and we'll take a deeper look.

Comment: @Sathya yeah I say 'admin' because when I try to flag undelete it said I can't do that since it is deleted by admin. Sure good people like you can take a deeper look but then whoever deleted my post will never learn from mistake right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post

- [Get rid of the Courier font](https://superuser.com/questions/448782/get-rid-of-the-courier-font/449815#449815)

Was flagged as spam. I did a bit of research and saw that you had posted only 2 answers on Super User, both mentioning this same software, hence I figured why it was flagged as spam.

However, I also took a look at your network profile and realized that you aren't a spammer, hence I rejected that spam flag, edited your post because the linked website was not accessible.

I didn't handle the other post, it might have been similarly spam flagged and auto-deleted.

Both have been undeleted.

Comment: Thanks, just want to say I raised bounty but no answer satisfied me so I researched and later found the answer, and I thought I might as well get some rep back by answering similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

With this answer:

[Get rid of the Courier font](https://superuser.com/questions/448782/get-rid-of-the-courier-font/449815#449815)

I would **highly** suggest that you improve upon it by adding more detail.  Whenever you find a program, or link that you feel is useful, put in the time to expound upon the answer instead of just posting a link and saying "This should help".

That would be a reason why I would personally down-vote a post like yours.  If you find yourself adding content from other sites, add a summary of the steps that need to be performed.  If you're adding a link to a specific product, give a summary of what it does, what it looks like and how to use it.

Here's are some examples of both product and instructions that I took from another site:

- [How to know if your computer is hit by a dnschanger virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/446315/how-to-know-if-your-computer-is-hit-by-a-dnschanger-virus/452356#452356)
- [How do I recover or "undelete" files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted/449551#449551)

Comment: Okay, I'll improve it when I have time. Basically it is a GUI frontend to do what he does manually. However I see many answers like this, even in links you provided.